# What's the name of this piano theme in My Hero Academia?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What's the name of the piano theme that plays when Sero and Kirishima make fun of Bakugou's hairstyle from Best Jeanist?

Answer (score 1):

The song's called "I'll become a hero", here's the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6KeN9G9IkU)! It is from the 1st Season's OST